# Android java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied) while inserting value into sql server through Web service

Tags: java, android, web-services

In my project I am trying to insert user details in to sql server by calling the webservice,while i am connecting to the webservice, java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied) warning appear in logcat, below is my code. I can't insert the values into the sql server.

RegisterToServer.java

```
public class RegisterToServer extends AsyncTask<UserDetails, Void, Void> {

    String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/RegisterUser";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME1 = "RegisterUser";

    String URL="http://192.168.0.100/panictest/WebService2.asmx";

    private String TAG = "RegisterUser";

    String responseString;
    String responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(UserDetails... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        RegToServer(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        // Display the progress bar

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }

    private void RegToServer(UserDetails user) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
        request.addProperty("mobileNumber", user.getMobilNumber());
        request.addProperty("userName", user.getUserName());
        request.addProperty("address", user.getAddress());
        Log.i("TAG","Inside regtoserver before webservice call"+user.getAddress());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;


        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);


            Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();


            Log.i("GET ROAD TAX", "Websevice called");



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.panicbutton"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

[image: Logcat]

Comment: Do you have the internet permission on your manifest?

Comment: share you logcat error

Comment: yes i have the internet permission.

Comment: And how are you defining the permission? Care to show us your manifest?

Comment: posted my manifest file

Comment: Your URL="http://192.168.0.100/..." is a local accessible only IP. This may cause the denial if your phone is not in the same local network.

Comment: Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` too

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```